# android studio doesn't update

Tags: android-studio, updates, gitignore

I'm trying to update my Android Studio, but unfortunately, it fails. It's true that I've modified the project_ignore file from the installation folder and now it complains about it. I've found it as a solution to have it as default .gitignore file.

I'm talking about file:
`..plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidProject\root\project_ignore`

I've tried to delete and to restore the content of that file but this doesn't work. I've tried 3-4 times to make the update. Maybe I didn't find the original content of that file.

How can I tell Android studio to ignore that file when it does the update. What other choices do I have besides doing a fresh reinstall?